# Does a nanosleep() in main thread affect other threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

My question is about the function `nanosleep` in c unix. If I put a `nanosleep` in the `main` function, will the other threads be affected by that?

Comment: Yes it can affect the other threads - it will likely give the other threads more execution time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

No, only the "*current*" thread is suspended.

The `main()` function runs in the main thread of the program, suspending it with `nanosleep()` will only suspend the main thread, all other threads will continue to execute normally.

From the [`nanosleep(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) manual page

> `nanosleep()` suspends the execution of the calling thread until either
>          at least the time specified in *req has elapsed, or the delivery of a
>          signal that triggers the invocation of a handler in the calling
>          thread or that terminates the process.

In POSIX (which is more general than unix) you can make the main thread block until another threads exits by using [`pthread_join()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html).

Comment: I believe some historical man pages wrongly said "process" rather than "thread" here - that may be the source of the OP's confusion. But this answer is completely correct.

Comment: @R.. I am not sure if in all cases said man pages were exactly wrong, if I recall processes predate threads, at least in the Unix and Linux world and thus at the time it was correct to say process there.

Comment: @Vality: I'm pretty sure the `nanosleep` function is sufficiently new that POSIX already had threads at the time it was added. It seems to have been added in Issue 5 (SUSv2) which included threads.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!!